# Data creation Error creating a kafka message to producer - Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING

Tags: avro

I am testing a avro format data using the below schema

```
{
    "namespace": "de.leyland.audit",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "AuditDataChangeleyland",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "machineID",  "type": "string"},
        {"name": "correlationId",  "type": "string"},
        {"name": "timestamp",  "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"},
    {"name": "machinescreen","type":{"type": "enum", "name": "BlockScreen", "symbols": ["NO","YES"]}},
    {"name": "entitlements", "type": ["null",{
    "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "name": "entitlements",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "name",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

when i was trying to create a sample data in json format based on the above avsc for kafka consumer i am getting the below error upn testing

```
{
  "machineID": "ahdzeha46",
  "correlationId": "473363621",
  "timestamp": "2021-08-09T12:20:15",
  "machinescreen": "NO",
  "correlationId": "corr-473363621",
  "entitlements": [
  {
    "entitlements": "machinerepair"
  }
 ]
}
```

how to rectify and create the sample data for testing ?

Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING

i have tried creating the sample json data based on the avsc schema and also prepared the json data as per the avsc schema however i am getting the above error

Comment: If you're using Java, stop using JSON... Write actual Java objects to Kafka and use Kafka Avro Serializer in your producer

Comment: And you have a similar problem as your last question. 1) Timestamp needs to be a number. 2) You need `"entitlements": {"array": [{ "name": "machinerepair" }]`, and notice that the key of your record in the array is `name` since you have `"name":"name"` in the schema...